# Image Not Loading In OpenCV 4.x.x

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

**[ UPDATE ]**

This issue is still unresolved. I have also asked it in the OpenCV forum ([here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/220988/image-not-loading-in-opencv-4xx/)) but failed to get any solution. Thus, I have uploaded videos to explain the problem. So, Kindly take a look for clarification.

- [OpenCV 4.x.x Image Reading Not Working](https://youtu.be/oG1D4ay98lA)
- [OpenCV 3.x.x Image Reading Working](https://youtu.be/UklDsZI9FNk)

---

I am not sure if I am the only one facing this issue. But In my machine, images are not loading in *OpenCV 4.x.x*. I have tried *4.0.0 (prebuilt x64 Windows binaries)*, *4.1.1(prebuilt x64 Windows binaries)* and *4.1.2(built x64 binaries from source using VS 2019)*.

Interestingly, the same code works for *OpenCV 3.x.x*.

Am I missing something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Mat image;
    string imagePath = filesystem::current_path().string() + "\\images\\road.jpg";

    cout << "Image Path : " << imagePath << "\n";

    image = imread(imagePath, IMREAD_COLOR);

    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout << "ERROR READING IMAGE!";
        return -1;
    }


    String windowTitle = "Hello OpenCV";
    namedWindow(windowTitle, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow(windowTitle, image);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Development Environment**

- Windows 10 64 Bit
- Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition

Comment: Debugging questions that come to my mind are: 1. Is the path correct? 2. Do you have read permissions for this file? 3. Can you load the file with an image viewer? 4. Can you load other file formats (bmp, png) with imread()?

Comment: @Tobias 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. Yes 4. Yet to try. I think the main thing is that the exact same code works with OpenCV 3.x.x. When I change to OpenCV 4.x.x, the imread() returns empty.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows 10 64 Bit, **Visual Studio Prof. 2017** for OpenCV 3.4.0 (Debug), OpenCV 4.0.0 / 4.1.0 (Debug, Release) and JPG and PNG images. In Visual Studio 2017, I had to use `std::experimental::filesystem::` instead of just `filesystem::`.